# How to use function_score on nested geo_point field

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I've been trying to use `function_score` on nested `geo_type` but Elasticsearch always returns documents with `_score` = 1.

My mapping

```
{
   "myindex": {
      "mappings": {
         "offers": {
            "properties": {
               "country_id": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "created_at": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
               },               
               "locations": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "city": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "store": true,
                        "fields": {
                           "city_original": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "coordinates": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                     }
                  }
               }               
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that some of documents can have empty coordinates. My query:

```
GET /myindex/offers/_search?explain
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "locations",
         "query": {
            "function_score": {
               "functions": [
                  {
                     "filter": {
                        "exists": {
                           "field": "locations.coordinates"
                        }
                     },
                     "gauss": {
                        "locations.coordinates": {
                           "origin": {
                              "lat": 49.1,
                              "lon": 17.03333
                           },
                           "scale": "10km",
                           "offset": "20km"
                        }                        
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As I said, Elasticsearch returns documents with `_score` = 1 and explanation: *Score based on child doc range from 21714 to 21714*

What am I doing wrong? My version of Elastisearch is 1.7.